# Can retrieve some orders, but not all. using Shopify REST API

Tags: api, shopify, shopify-api

Trying to determine why I am not able to retrieve all orders under my test store (so that I can understand what is happening in Production as well)
[image: all orders]

As you can see above, I have 13 orders placed on my test store, but I can only retrieve 11. The two orders placed in august, that I have marked in red, are not reachable. Even when I try to look them up by searching by their ID's

Requests I am using:
sharing my access token here, its fine. this is just a test store.
X-Shopify-Access-Token: `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`

`https://vitor-dawn-dev-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-10/orders.json?status=any` - gives me the 11 orders

`https://vitor-dawn-dev-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-10/orders/count.json?status=any` - returns 13 (The number I expected).

`https://vitor-dawn-dev-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-10/orders/4062335991963.json` - one of the missing order's ID. gives me a 404 Not found.

Some sample IDS:

Valid and reachable order ID sample: `4270842052763`

Order ID's that aren't reachable: `4062335991963` and `4062362665115`

Also tried through graphQL, but got the same results.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Shopify REST API](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-10/resources/order#top) docs for Orders

> Only the last 60 days' worth of orders from a store are accessible
> from the Order resource by default. If you want to access older
> orders, then you need to request access to all orders. If your app is
> granted access, then you can add the read_all_orders scope to your app
> along with read_orders or write_orders. Private apps are not affected
> by this change and are automatically granted the scope.

Your app needs **read_all_orders** scope to be able to fetch data for orders created more that 60 days ago.

Comment: This makes sense @Bilal Akbar.
I tried requesting this scope some time ago, but did not receive a reply, since this is my test app. But it is fine then. thank you!